# FileLoadException: The file is in use

Tags: c#, uwp

My task is to write data, which is coming from the sensor 30 times per second, to a `.csv` file. If the sersor sends wrong data, I do not write it and just wait. If the data is ok again, I need to create a new file and start to write the data there. Here is my code:

```
class FileWriter
{
    string filename;

    public FileWriter()
    {

    }

    public void SetFilename(string filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public async void WriteData(string data)
    {

        StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(stream.Size))
        {
            using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outputStream))
            {
                dataWriter.WriteString(data);

                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();

            }
            await outputStream.FlushAsync();
        }
        stream.Dispose();
    }

}
```

But I always get:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in 
System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
WinRT information: The file is in use. Please close the file before continuing.
FileLoadException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I think, it's because the file opens async and it has no time to be opened 30 times per second. But I have no idea how to fix it.

**EDIT:** more details.
I took [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-230). There is a class `SpatialMappingObserver`, which has a method `Update()`, which is called 30 times per second. There I call my `WriteData()` to write the state of Hololens Camera in the file. Because the `Update()` isn't async, I cannot call `await WriteData()`.

Comment: Lastly, add this code (if you're using C#, within the inner using statement) to save the text to your file with DataWriter.StoreAsync and close the stream with IOutputStream.FlushAsync.

C#

Copy
await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
await outputStream.FlushAsync();  <= yours is outside it... seems much of your code is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files Re-go over it (maybe? the web site).  I will try to create a boiler plate as well if I get time.

Comment: I see many possible things that can go wrong with your code, however I suspect that the issue is not within the lines you have posted. As for those - first and most important you are using **async void** and this is no good, I also suspect that you may try to run this as fire-forget just like WriteData() without awaiting this. Second thing is - why haven't you put `var stream` also in using statement and just manually dispose?

Comment: As for the reason of the error, are you trying to write data couple of times to the same file? If so then why to create the file each time? Can't you create file once, hold the stream to it and write when needed? Also other design may be to buffer the data and write with some intervals. As for async - are you using any synchronization objects to prevent race conditions/guard the files? Nevertheless to get the answer you will need to post more code, especially the part where and how WriteData is being called.

Comment: Yes, I call `WriteData()` directly without awaiting it. And I have no synchronization. It means I have weak knowledges in C#. I just have no idea how to do it properly.

Comment: @Romasz is right, you can replace the try...finally below with a using statement they are equivalent, but the using is much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a lock to ensure only one thread is writing the file at a given time like this :

```
class FileWriter
{
    static readonly object _filelock = new object();
    string filename;

    public FileWriter()
    {

    }

    public void SetFilename(string filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public async void WriteData(string data)
    {
        lock (_filelock) 
        {

            StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            using(var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(stream.Size))
                {
                    using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outputStream))
                    {
                        dataWriter.WriteString(data);

                        await dataWriter.StoreAsync();

                    }
                    await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I think that your CreationCollisionOption must be set to OpenIfExists.

Comment: Can you add the call to WriteData to the question ? Have you awaited it ?

Comment: Yes, I call `WriteData()` directly without awaiting it. And I have no synchronization. It means I have weak knowledges in C#. I just have no idea how to do it properly.

Comment: You need to ensure that last WriteData method call is finished before calling it again with the same filename. To do so, you need at least to await the WriteData call, but maybe it's not enough. Do you know the code that trigger the write ? Also you need to change the CreationCollisioOption Flag to OpenIfExists if you intended to write multiple time in the same file when there are no error. (I will update my answer accordingly)

Comment: It look like we can really be sure when the update happend, in this case, you could use a lock. I updated my answer.